# ¿Cómo ver qué archivos son diferentes entre 2 ramas con Git?

Tags: git

Lo que quiero es saber cuales archivos son diferentes entre 2 ramas de mi repositorio con Git.

Como si se tratara de `diff`, creo que debe ser posible ver la diferencia de las 2 listas de archivos de ambas ramas.

Answer (score 16):

Básicamente el comando para ver las diferencias entre dos branches es:

```
$ git diff branch1..branch2
```

Para listar qué archivos han cambiado entre dos branches puedes usar `--name-status`:

```
$ git diff --name-status branch1..branch2
```

Para mayor detalle, puedes usar [`difftool`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool) con alguna herramienta. Por ejemplo yo la uso con [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: interesante lo de los archivos que han cambiado entre los 2 branches!, gracias.

Comment: @Elenasys de nada ;)

Comment: Meld es una excelente herramienta

Answer (score 5):

Creo que encontré una solución.

```
$ git diff --stat master..dev
```

Ademas, es posible añadir algo de color.

```
$ git diff --stat --color master..dev
```

Comment: También es válido, solo que no tienes el estado del archivo (`M`, `A`)

Comment: Pero al menos veo las diferencias entre ambas listas, incluyendo el número de lineas nuevas, eliminadas o diferentes.

Comment: No se si eso te ayude mucho, pensé que la idea era saber cuales eran esos archivos, si quieres algo mas detallado mejor usas `difftool` con una herramienta tipo Meld, por ejemplo.

Comment: Creo que ambas son útiles, pero me sirvió mas --stat. Gracias.

Answer (score 4):

#### Solución #1 - Archivo por archivo

Diferencias de archivos entre dos ramas (comparando branches):

```
$ git diff branch1 branch2    (1)
$ git diff branch1..branch2   (2)
$ git diff branch1...branch2  (3)
```

1. Cambios entre branch1 y branch2.
2. Lo mismo que la primera.

[image: Captura de git diff - solución 1 y 2]

3. Los cambios que se produjeron en la rama **branch2** desde que la **branch1** comenzó fuera de esa.

[image: Captura de git diff - solución 3]

---

#### Solución #2 - Por listado

Si lo que deseas es obtener un listado de los archivos, puedes usar argumentos como:

`--stat`: Muestra una diferencia a nivel binario.

```
$ git diff --stat branch1 branch2
```

[image: Captura del uso de --stat]

`--numstat`: Muestra en número base decimal las diferencias en líneas.

```
$ git diff --numstat branch1 branch2
```

[image: Captura del uso de --numstat]

---

#### Herramientas adicionales

Añadiendo el argumento `--name-status` puedes listar los archivos que han cambiado entre 2 ramas:

```
$ git diff --name-status branch1..branch2
```

Para verificar los cambios de un archivo entre 2 ramas, usa:

```
$ git diff branch1 branch2 -- archivo.ext
```

Más información (inglés) en: [Git - git-diff Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)

Answer (score 3):

Tal y como se indica en [Showing which files have changed between two revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4949604/1983854), este comando:

```
git diff --stat --color branchA..branchB
```

Te da información sobre qué archivos son distintos entre `branchA` y `branchB`. Nótese que `--color` es opcional (¡pero útil!).

Por ejemplo en mi repositorio git me encuentro con diferencias del tipo:

```
 test.yaml   |   2 +-
 otro_test.yaml | 122 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 2 files changed, 40 insertions(+), 84 deletions(-)
```

Answer (score 2):

Queda con:

```
$ git diff branchA..branchB
```

o

```
$ git diff branchA branchB
```

Answer (score 2):

La respuesta de @Chofoteddy te da la información que necesitas pero hay una sintaxis alterna que puedes utilizar para comparar archivos entre dos ramas incluso si hubo un rename. La sintaxis es:

```
git diff branch:path_to_file anotherbranch:path_to_file
```

Por ejemplo si quieres ver los cambios entre dos README uno con extensión .md y otro sin extensión, el primero en la rama `develop` y el segundo en la rama `master`, utilizarías la siguiente sintaxis:

```
git diff develop:README.md master:README
```

Comment: Muy bien, aunque lo que buscaba era de forma general, cuales archivos tenían diferencias entre ambas, por lo que me sirvió mas git diff --stat rama1..rama2

Answer (score -3):

```
git diff branch-comparar branch-actual nombre-archivo
```

Comment: Esta respuesta fue reportada como de baja calidad por el sistema. Podrias mirar el [tour] y decir que aporta esta respuesta en comparacion a las otras que hay? mira por favor [answer]