# ¿Cómo puedo comparar el mismo archivo en diferentes ramas en GIT?

Tags: git, sourcetree

Tengo dos ramas en un proyecto que usa GIT, una contiene un cambio (rama A) y la otra contiene una alternativa a ese cambio (rama B).

Estoy usando SourceTree y el problema que tengo es que cuando estoy en la rama A, para ver el contenido del mismo fichero en la rama B debo cambiar a esa otra rama y entonces pierdo el contenido de la rama A en mi editor de código (IntelliJ), lo cual hace complicado comparar los contenidos.

¿Hay alguna manera o comando para comparar el contenido del mismo fichero en dos ramas diferentes en GIT?

Comment: Aunque la pregunta es ligeramente distinta en esta respuesta esta el comando para hacer eso: [compara ramas git](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1148/c%C3%B3mo-ver-qu%C3%A9-archivos-son-diferentes-entre-2-ramas-con-git#answer-1156)

Comment: y para IntelliJ: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/merging-deleting-and-comparing-branches.html

Comment: @blonfu Si pones esos comentarios como respuesta, como poco te llevarás mi +1

Comment: No se si merece la pena ponerlo como respuesta, son solo enlaces a otros sitios

Comment: La solución que mencionas en el primer comentario es parecida a la que Shaz menciona, pero curiosamente fue la que sugeriste en el segundo comentario (la de IntelliJ) la que me acabé utilizando más :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te refieres a realizar la comparación desde la línea de comando, normalmente utilizo esta sintaxis:

```
git diff rama1:./ruta/archivo rama2:./ruta/archivo
```

Estoy seguro que conoces la documentación de `git diff` pero para referencia de otros visitantes dejo el enlace: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff