# ¿Cómo comparar dos ramas en Git?

Tags: git, diff

Estoy haciendo el **"Tour of Heroes"** en ***Angular5***. Al finalizar crearé una ***nueva rama de Git*** en la que actualizaré el proyecto a ***Angular6***. El tutorial con la versión 5 lo estoy haciendo en una rama nombrada como *"toh5"*, con la versión 6 irá en *"tho6"*.

¿Cómo puedo hacer un **diff entre ambas ramas** para ver las diferencias entre ambas versiones?

Answer (score 3):

Para **ver las diferencias entre *rama1* y *rama2* en Git** usaremos el comando:

```
git diff rama1..rama2
```

Pueden usarse otras opciones para casos concretos, por ejemplo, [comparar sólo un fichero en ambas ramas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/26050):

```
git diff rama1:./ruta/archivo rama2:./ruta/archivo
```

Para ver más detalles y opciones disponibles tenemos la [documentación de Git sobre diff](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff).